# numbering sections in thesis

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I know these type of questions have been asked previously, but i am still having problem with the numbering of sections and subsections in my thesis. I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass\[12pt,a4paper,twoside\]{report}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

{\bf \underline{List of Abbreviations used in the thesis}}\\
ECM \quad \quad\quad\quad\quad Elliptic Curve Method

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1} 

\chapter{Introduction}
\input{chapters/Introduction}

\end{document}
```

and in Chapter Introduction, I have the following MWE:

```
In the first section of this chapter,...

\section{Elliptic Curves}

One of the major problems of...

\subsection{Curves of genus zero}
An important..

\subsection{Curves of genus one}
An elliptic..

\subsection{Curves of higher genus}

\section{Literature review}
```

I want the numbering to be :

```
1. Introduction
   1.1 Elliptic curves
       1.1.1   Curves of genus zero
       1.1.2   Curves of genus one
       1.1.3   Curves of higher genus
   1.2 Literature review
```

[image]

Comment: We cannot answer your question. There is sommething in your document causing the behaviour. This is certainly not normal. Please show us a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html).

Comment: You are just starting with LaTeX, right? Never trust the internet, it has given you commands that should not be used for 20 years now. Please have a look at [LaTeX for commplete novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/) for the very basics. Next volume in the series gives tipps for thesis writing.

Comment: There are (many) errors or deprecated commands in your document. We can't compile it, since we don't have the file `Introduction.tex` at hand. In my point of view, the question can be easily answered after knowing your file.

Comment: Running the above example (errors removed, which are not connected to the wrong numbering, however) I get exactly the numbering you want to have. The error must be in a part of the document you're not showing to us

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is rather meant as kick into the right direction...

I took the O.P.'s 'MWE' and removed the errors and the deprecated syntax parts, added (one of many ways, however) to provide the `List Of Abbreviations`.

However, the numbering is expected, not like in the O.P's screenshot.

Some other error must be occuring in a part of the original document which is not shown here, unfortunately.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[nomain,acronym,toc]{glossaries}


\makenoidxglossaries

\newacronym{ecm}{ECM}{Elliptic Curve Method}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\printnoidxglossary[type=acronym,title={List of Abbreviations used in the thesis},toctitle={List of Abbreviations}]


%% This is wrong/deprecated 
%{\bf \underline{List of Abbreviations used in the thesis}}\\
%ECM \quad \quad\quad\quad\quad Elliptic Curve Method
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
%\setcounter{page}{1} % Not necessary, since `\pagenumbering{arabic} sets the page counter always to 1 

\chapter{Introduction}



\section{Elliptic Curves}

One of the major problems of \gls{ecm}

\subsection{Curves of genus zero}
An important..

\subsection{Curves of genus one}
An elliptic..

\subsection{Curves of higher genus}

\section{Literature review}



\end{document}
```

[image]